# "Unknown filesystem unionfs" although all packages and modules are installed

Tags: 11.10, mount, fstab, unionfs

I'm trying to mount a `unionfs` file system in fstab (as one of the steps in [this guide](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=48)), with the following line:

```
unionfs /usr unionfs nodev,noatime,dirs=/.filesystems/usr/overlay=ro:/usr=rw 0 0
```

I've installed the package `unionfs-fuse` and added `unionfs` to `/etc/modules`, but when trying to `mount -a` I still get an error saying

> mount: unknown file system type: unionfs

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I wanted to tag this `unionfs`, but I don't have enough rep to create new tags. Anyone with 300+, feel free =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved (or rather worked around) this, by not using `unionfs` and instead using `aufs` - [another union file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs).

**Install the AUFS package and its kernel module from linux-image-extra-virtual:**

```
sudo apt-get install aufs-tools linux-image-extra-virtual
```

The corresponding row in my `fstab` now looks like this:

```
usr    /usr    aufs    udba=reval,br:/.filesystems/usr/rw:/.filesystems/usr/ro    0   0
```

The `squashfs` is mounted at `/.filesystems/usr/ro` in the previous line, making this working as a substitute for the troubling steps in [the guide I referred to in the OP](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=48).

Comment: That didn't solve it for me, I got the same unknown FS error with AUFS.

Answer (score 0):

Create underlying squashfs on loop device through the terminal:

```
/.filesystems/usr/usr.sqfs /usr squashfs ro,loop,nodev 0 0
```

Create aufs virtual filesystem that allows you to write on it:

```
aufs /usr aufs nodev,noatime,dirs=/.filesystems/usr/overlay=rw:/usr=ro 0 0
```

Also consider adjusting `/etc/sysctl.conf` (!) if shutting down your PC takes longer than it should. Decrease the swap - swap turned off below

```
vm.swappiness = 0
m.dirty_background_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 0
vm.dirty_ratio = 80
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 0
```